# What is the relationship between stroke volume of blood and ventricular end-diastolic volume?

Tags: cardiology, blood-circulation

I do know what each term means. That is, i know that **stroke volume** is: the volume of blood pumped by each contraction of a ventricle, while **ventricular end-diastolic volume** is: the volume of blood in the ventricle just before systole. However I can't relate the two in terms of, say, graphs or in the mode of action of the heart between this period(s).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Both are simply volumes of blood. They are different because not all of the blood in the ventricle is ejected. It sounds like you're asking about the [cardiac cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_cycle), not volumes, but I'm not sure. (The red line is the graphic "relationship" between the two.)

Comment: Thanks! I did see this diagram before on Wikipedia but i might have overlooked the label of ventricular volume. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest relationship is "EDV=SV+ESV", "EF=SV/EDV" (EDV: end-diastolic volume, SV: stroke volume, ESV: end-systolic volume, EF: ejection fraction)